# Configure a maven project with sub-modules without an aggregator project

Tags: java, maven, war

We originally had one large maven project that built a war.  I'm trying to extract a portion of the code out into a separate module so it can be reused in another project.

What I tried doing is creating a new maven project under the original one and moving all the source code I wanted separated over to it, then adding it as a <module> in the original project.  i.e.

```
pom.xml
    src
sub-module
    pom.xml
    src
```

In the original pom I added the module using:

```
<modules>
    <module>sub-module</module>
</modules>
```

My issue is on the original pom, it won't build the war any more - it will only build a parent.pom - I can't use
<packaging>war<packaging> -- it insists on <packaging>pom<packaging>

Is it possible to get this to work with just the two maven projects?  Or do I need to create a brand-new maven project to be the parent and do nothing but combine the war and the jar projects?  My main goal was trying to avoid having a new root for the project structure since we have scripts that depend on war code being in the root.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand here. You should have one parent of type POM, one module which contains your extracted code of type JAR and one module of type WAR.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid that parent pom?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid it? The parent is there to group those two module together so they can live the same build.

Comment: Primarily to avoid having to change a lot of other processes that depend on resources being in the root/src/main/resources directory and the war file ending up in root/target.  We have a big automation process built around building the root project and running stuff that results.  If the root became just an empty parent we'd have to rework the automated process and that is another group with another release cycle.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But separating code in two modules require this change really.

Comment: Furthermore if you are working with Maven this is one of the foundations separation of concerns which mean the root does not have code nor resources cause there will not being built a jar file from it...